# How to get nice syntax error messages with Happy?

Tags: haskell, happy

I am currently playing with the happy parser generator.

Other parser generators can give nice messages like "unexpected endline, expected  'then'".
With happy I just get the current Tokens and the position of the error.

Can you give me an example of how to get error messages like above?

Comment: You can add extra right-hand sides to each production to catch known errors. Make sure to always add them at the end, otherwise you will upset the precedence of the grammar.

Comment: It's not generally possible to do this, due to the way Happy works - it's a traditional LALR(1) table-based parser, and the information you need to generate the error is not easily available at runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a Happy feature that I have authored for this purpose.

See my blog post: [Toward better GHC syntax errors](http://blog.aloni.org/posts/toward-better-ghc-syntax-errors/)

It was merged in this pull request [RFC: On parse error - show the next possible tokens](https://github.com/simonmar/happy/pull/46).

Comment: This was finally released in Happy 1.19.7. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, this is [documented here](https://monlih.github.io/happy-docs/#_sec_errorhandlertype_directive). (My own build of the Happy documentation that's up to date)

Comment: Thanks for implementing this @Dan Aloni, this is amazing!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, from what I've heard, if you want nice parser errors, use [Parsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec/) instead of Happy.

Comment: I tried Parsec now but the definition of the grammer is very verbose compared to happy and also quite hard to read.

But it does give the kind of error messages which I wanted.